# How to Save result into new table in same Database PHP

Tags: php

I want to save results from result normalitation to another table in same database.  For example, before counting using php, I used `table1` for raw data and use it for calculate `Normalitation Matriks`.  I want to save results into new `table2`.

codes:

```php
<?php
 //use connection
 include("koneksi.php");
 //width 
 $bobot = array(0.50, 0.35, 0.15);

 //show Name
 function getNama($id){
  $q =mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbcalon where idCalon = '$id'");
  $d = mysql_fetch_array($q);
  return $d['nama'];
 }

 //Select table tbmatrik
 $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbmatrik");
 //Buat tabel untuk menampilkan hasil
 echo "<H3>Matrik Awal</H3>
 <table width=500 style='border:1px; #ddd; solid; border-collapse:collapse' border=1>
  <tr>
   <td>No</td><td>Nama</td><td>Jarak</td><td>Harga</td><td>Fasilitas</td>
  </tr>
  ";
 $no = 1;
 while ($dt = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
  echo "<tr>
   <td>$no</td><td>".getNama($dt['idCalon'])."</td><td>$dt[Kriteria1]</td><td>$dt[Kriteria2]</td><td>$dt[Kriteria3]</td>
  </tr>";
 $no++;
 }
 echo "</table>";

 //Normalitation
 $crMax = mysql_query("SELECT max(Kriteria1) as maxK1, 
      max(Kriteria2) as maxK2,
      max(Kriteria3) as maxK3
   FROM tbmatrik");
 $max = mysql_fetch_array($crMax) or die("Query failed with error: ".mysql_error());

 //Count Normalitation
 $sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbmatrik");
 //Buat tabel untuk menampilkan hasil
 echo "<H3>Matrik Normalisasi</H3>
 <table width=500 style='border:1px; #ddd; solid; border-collapse:collapse' border=1>
  <tr>
   <td>No</td><td>Nama</td><td>Jarak</td><td>Harga</td><td>Fasilitas</td>
  </tr>
  ";
 $no = 1;
 while ($dt2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)) {

  echo "<tr>
   <td>$no</td><td>".getNama($dt2['idCalon'])."</td><td>".round($dt2['Kriteria1']/$max['maxK1'],2)."</td><td>".round($dt2['Kriteria2']/$max['maxK2'],2)."</td><td>".round($dt2['Kriteria3']/$max['maxK3'],2)."</td>          
        </tr>";
 $no++;
 }
 echo "</table>";

//
```

Comment: Here, i'm not seeing any `INSERT` statement. Where have you tried ?

Comment: yes i want to use insert statement but i have tried to used it before it was fail. i dont know where to place insert statement into my PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

Just use something like this?

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table2(/*insert table field names here*/) VALUES (value1, value2, value3 etc...)";
$result = mysqli_query($connectionName, $query);
```